# Setup project always clean installation

Tags: installation, windows-installer, setup-project, orca

I have a setup made by Setup Project for my application. Is there a possibility to make my setup not check for any installed versions of a product?

I want it to work in this way: whenever I open my setup I want it to do a clean install. I don't want to have any repair option, but I want it to allways overwrite the installed product.

Is there a possibility to achieve it in Windows Installer? Are there any properties I could change in Orca to achieve it?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to stop registering the package with Windows Installer. To do that you need to remove the following standard actions from **InstallExecuteSequence** table:

- RegisterUser
- RegisterProduct
- PublishFeatures
- PublishProduct

Just so you know, this will also make the product to not be listed in Control Panel, list of install programs.